# Что такое матрица-покрытия?

Tags: тестирование

Собственно вопрос к тестерам и тем, кто связан с тестированием.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Тестовое Покрытие (Test Coverage)](http://www.protesting.ru/testing/testcoverage.html)
- [Модульное тестирование. Зачем, как и кто](http://citforum.ru/SE/testing/unit_testing/)
- [Как мы Code Coverage измеряли](http://bugscatcher.net/archives/1103)

Думаю, что эти статьи чуточку прояснят ситуацию.

Comment: @Sharbag Большое спасибо, почитаю обязательно.

Comment: Кстати, на английском языке на эту тему больше информации. Если не боитесь английского то погуглите по запросу coverage matrix.